# The Vpc link is not yet available for deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following the instrutions at https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-four/

```
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id a2kpkzqme1 --stage-name prod
```

An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateDeployment operation: The Vpc link is not yet available for deployment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. So I checked the status of creation of the VPC Link:

```
aws apigateway get-vpc-link --vpc-link-id MY_VPC_LINK_ID
```

It showed, that creation failed:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxx",
    "name": "MysfitsApiVpcLink",
    "targetArns": [
        "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:MY_REGION:MY_ID:loadbalancer/net/mysfits-nlb"
    ],
    "status": "FAILED",
    "statusMessage": "NLB ARN is malformed",
    "tags": {}
}
```

So the failure I made was a wrong NLB ARN. I forgot something at the end.

I repeated all steps from the creation of the VPC Link (with right NLB ARN). Then it worked for me.